# Added httpd to group but webserver still cannot access files - CentOS

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, centos

I want to allow web access to files without allowing other system users access to the files for the website.

I have owner:group as

bob:bob

Then I did:

usermod -a -G bob httpd

To add http to the user group.

File permissions on root folder are:

```
drwxr-xr--
```

But I cannot access the site from the internet anymore. The web server should be able to access the folder with the above permissions.

If I add o+x permission, it works immediately.

error log says:

```
[Tue May 01 17:25:20 2012] [crit] [client xxx.xx.xxx.xx] (13)Permission denied:
/var/www/bob/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it i
s readable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the owner/group present in your `httpd.conf` file?  They belong under the `server.username` and `server.groupname` settings, respectively.  Also, you might need to change the owner of the root directory (as well as all files and subdirectories) to `bob:bob` with `chown`.

Comment: If httpd had access to the /var/www/bob dir before, then I don't think I need to worry about permissions on /var/www, right?
In httpd.conf it is set to run as user:group apache:apache. But if it is also part of group bob shouldn't it have access to the dir?

Comment: It depens what MPM Apache is set to run with.  Are you certain that processes to **that** folder run as apache:apache?  It could be that for security the Apache config may be set to run as a different user.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know what MPM it's running with but changing the group in httpd.conf to "bob" did give apache access to the folder. I'm not sure, though, why the filesystem wouldn't give access to the folder to a user that's supposed to be in the group. Perhaps the MPM overrides that setting and defines apache as belonging ONLY to the group specified in httpd.conf, and not to any other group?

Answer (score 1):

If you have SELinux enabled, it could cause these issues. Checking `/etc/selinux/config` will tell you if it is. If so, then the proper contexts would need to be applied to the files apache is trying to access.

Changing the user in `httpd.conf` should be the last thing to do, typically you want `httpd` running a low-number service user, such as `apache` itself.

```
ls -lZ /var/www
```

would show the contexts. `sestatus` will let you know the status of SELinux on your system. Apache is definitely a 'Targeted' app. checking the SELinux logs will also show the access violation.

By the way, disabling SELinux is *not* the way to go.